# how to delete database row as DataGrid row is deleted in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my wpf project which is bound to a datasource and is successfully getting populated with values. Now problem is, how do i respond when user is deleting a row. I also want to delete the same row in database also. My approach is to get the id from `lbId` column of currently selected row and issue a DELETE query when user presses Delete button on keyboard or the `Delete Button` in my GUI . How am i supposed to do this?.

Or alternatively Isn't there any thing like `UserDeletingRow` as in Winforms `DataGridView`?

Here is the XAML

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="430" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="378,61,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="550" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LocalBookmarks}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" Grid.Row="5" RowEditEnding="datagrid1_RowEditEnding" DataGridRow.Selected="datagrid1_RowSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="20" Binding="{Binding Path=lbId}" CanUserResize="False"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Width="225" Binding="{Binding Path=TitleOfPage}" MaxWidth="250" CanUserResize="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn CanUserResize="True" Header="Link" MaxWidth="300" MinWidth="250" Binding="{Binding Path=SiteAddress}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Saved On" Width="70" Binding="{Binding Path=DateAdded}" CanUserResize="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is the image of DataGrid.
[image: And just in case the image helps, here it is]

Here is the binding code:

```
private void BindToData(SqlCeConnectionManger s, int gt, int lt)
    {
        SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LocalBookmarks WHERE lbId > " + gt.ToString() + " AND lbId < " + lt.ToString() + " ORDER BY DateAdded DESC", s.SqlCeCon);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(dataset, "LocalBookmarks");
        dataGrid1.DataContext = dataset;
        s.SqlCeCon.Close();     

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a column that contains a button.  The button will have parameters that will be able to identify the key.  Then program the button for validation, remove from list, remove from the database, and then refresh the datagrid.  I use mvvm with c# and XML, but no code behind.  Check out onpropertychanged("propertyname").

Answer (score 1):

I got here to a relatively late posting/answer looking for something else...

```
Sub dg_RowEditEnding(sender As Object, e As DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs) Handles dg.RowEditEnding
```

This is the event I use to sync my datagrids with the database backend...

Answer (score 0):

if you bind to ado.net dataset/datatable it will automatically deleted from your dataset/datatable too if the use click "Del".

all you have to do then is to call Update on your TabelAdapter to get the changes to your database.

EDIT: btw you can call "RejectChanges" to get the deleted rows back as long you did not call AcceptChanges.